# How do I get the jquery-tools tabs-accordion extend to the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools

I am currently building a ui with jquery-tools, and I have run into a problem where the accordion only extends as far as it needs to.  Is there any way I could have the tabs extend all the way down the container?  I need something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+ (container)
|tab (open)                                |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|(end of content)                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|(tab)                                     |
|(tab)                                     |
|(tab)                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried making the container height 100%, the tab height 100%, but the number of tabs isn't constant (will change based on user).  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Set `autoHeight: false` in the accordion options.  This should allow you to set your own height with css, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly explained in the [jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#fillspace)

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistagged as jquery-tabs.  It's jquery-tools